# Adding tracking codes via Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I often find myself adding things like google, facebook, and linkedin tracking codes to websites. The way I usually do it is something like this

```
$('body').on('click','.CLASS’, function (e){
    window.lintrk('track', { conversion_id: ###### });
    // ^ this is what likendin ones usually look like when they get to me

    return true;
});
```

Now today I got a tracking code that didnt look like the above `window.lintrk` that I'm used too, instead it came more like this `<script async src='https://tag.simpli.fi/sifitag/#####-#####-#####'></script>` so my question is can I just slap that into my click function as usual and will it work?

```
$('body').on('click','.CLASS’, function (e){
    <script async src='https://tag.simpli.fi/sifitag/#####-#####-#####'></script>

    return true;
});
```

Comment: You can just add it directly to the HTML. Either in the head or before the closing body tag.

Comment: @ruleboy21 I need the tracker to fire once the action of the button click has been preformed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that something like this should work, I will remove this answer if I'm not getting tracked results during the week!

```
$('body').on('click','.CLASS', function (e){
    $.getScript("https://tag.simpli.fi/sifitag/#####-#####-#####");

    return true;
});
```

and I hope I'm using the [.getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) function correctly here